# Displaying Markers from XML depending on element value

Tags: javascript, xml, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

I can't seem to get my head around using google maps api. I'm trying to display markers only for those xml elements that match what address a user has typed into an input box.

My XML file is as follows:

```
<rentalProperties>
 <property available="yes" contact="0423020892">
 <type>house</type>
 <price>800</price>
 <address>
  <streetNo>116</streetNo>     
  <street>Warrigal Road</street>
  <suburb>Camberwell</suburb>
  <state>VIC</state>
  <zipcode>3124</zipcode>
 </address>
<numberOfBedrooms>4</numberOfBedrooms>
<description>Ideal for the familly...</description>
</rentalProperties>
```

Im confused also about using the geocoder.getLatLng() to convert the inputbox address into lat and long. Here is my current javascript code.

```
var map = null;
var geocoder = null;

var xmlhttp = null;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

function load() 
{
if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) 
{
    map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));
    map.addControl(new GSmallMapControl());
    map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());
    map.addControl(new GScaleControl());
    geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();
    geocoder.getLatLng("Melbourne", function(point){map.setCenter(point, 15)}); 
    placeMarkers();
   }
}

function addMarker(){
var street = document.getElementById("street").value;
var suburb = document.getElementById("suburb").value;
var address = street + suburb;
geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();
geocoder.getLatLng(address, function(point) {
    if (!point) {
        alert(address + " not found");
    } 
    else{
        map.setCenter(point, 12);
        map.addOverlay(createMarker(point, address));
        //saveMarker(point, address);
    }
});
}

function placeMarkers() //loading up the XML file
{
GDownloadUrl("http://mercury.it.swin.edu.au/hit3324/7186975/Assignment3/data/apartment.xml", function(data, responseCode) {
    if(responseCode == 200){
        var xml = GXml.parse(data);  //convert the data to an XML DOM fragment; will get from cache if not cleared
        var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("property");  // get the marker elements in the data
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            var xmlStNo = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("streetNo");
            var xmlStreet = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("street");
            var xmlSuburb = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("suburb");
            var xmlAddress = xmlStNo + xmlStreet + xmlSuburb;
            geocoder = new GClientGeocoder(); 
            var point = geocoder.getLatLng(xmlAddress, function(point));
            map.setCenter(point, 12);   //fails if this not used
            map.addOverlay(createMarker(point, markers[i].getAttribute("address"))); 
        }
    }
    else if(responseCode == -1) {
        alert("Data request timed out. Please try later.");
    }
    else { 
        geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();
        geocoder.getLatLng("Paris", function(point){map.setCenter(point, 13)}); 
    }

});
}

function createMarker(point, address) {  
var marker = new GMarker(point); 
GEvent.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
    marker.openInfoWindowHtml(address);  });  
return marker;
}
```

Also if i've done this the long way and there is a simplified version that would be great. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Is there anything specific in the code that is not working? Any errors thrown?

Comment: no errors, but my map does not even display. I'm mostly just want to be able to ready through my xml if nothing else

Comment: First, make sure that the DOM has been loaded before you create the map. Second, see if the map HTML element has a width and height specified.

Comment: I suggest creating a jsfiddle so anyone can take a look at the full code you're using - jsfiddle.net

Comment: great idea, http://jsfiddle.net/QnU6Z/

i would just like to run through my xml and display the markers but I cant get that working either. How do i access the elements that are within the address element?

Comment: It seems some scripts are missing in the jsfiddle. Specifically, map.js which it tries to load locally, but it needs a full path.